# Can we access the HTML Controls to Server Side in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

Hi could any one help me regarding the accessibility of HTML controls to Server Side ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add runat="server" attribute to your HTML elements to access them at server side.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article:
http://odetocode.com/articles/348.aspx

You can add runat="server" and use controls in `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` namespace to access it.